# Simple paper cuts problem

Tags: geometry

If the cuts of a piece of paper were done the way as shown, which of the four possibilities would we get?

[image]

I drew out the whole piece of paper, but instead of cuts I just drew black lines, and with them I get confused, because it should be real cuts instead. Not sure which one would match.

Comment: Since this is a multiple-choice question, I think the way to get the right answer with the least effort is to just focus on the shape and orientation of the center hole. Try mentally cutting and unfolding the paper, or draw out what it would look like.

Comment: So why didn't you just try it?

Comment: Seems to me that the easiest way to prove that it's #4 is to just get scissors and paper and try it.

Comment: By elimination method, the option 4 is correct answer. Cutting a right angled triangle will always result in a square which points to option 4

Answer (score 17):

It should not be difficult to unfold this with your lines.

Something like this

[image]

Alternatively draw some lines on the the possible solutions

[image]

Comment: Could we know the tool for this beautiful graphic?

Comment: @Przemysław Scherwentke: [Microsoft Paint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint)

Comment: Drawing the folded piece on the possible answers - nice way to think around the problem.

Answer (score 6):

HINT: The shape of the triangle on the left eliminates (2) and (3). Which one of the remaining two is eliminated by the cut near scissors on the picture?

Comment: Note that the center hole already rules out all but one possibility ;)

Comment: oh yeah the square one 4

Comment: @JackiePoehler Yes! If it means the solution, not elimination.

Comment: @AlexR Yes, but in this order it is probably easier to see perpendicular lines in the  removed triangles.